# Error in signif(attr(x, "bbox"), options("digits")$digits) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Tags: r, r-sf

I'm trying to plot points on a map using the `sf` package. How do I turn a `tibble` data frame in to an sf object? Or better, how do I turn the Lat and longitude columns in a POINT geometry column? So far I get an error on the `bbox` attribute:

```
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           Error in signif(attr(x, "bbox"), options("digits")$digits) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

My example dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
   
df <- structure(list(location = c(503L, 568L), lat = c("52.3659590000371", 
    "52.0666223921085"), long = c("4.83672532849487", "4.30615760417214"
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L))
```

My code:

```
st_as_sf(df, 
         coords = c("long", "lat"), 
         crs = 4289)
```

these are the bbox coordinates of the Netherlands: `(3.31497114423, 50.803721015, 7.09205325687, 53.5104033474)`

How do I adjust the `bbox` attribute so that I can plot a map?
All help much appreciated.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, what is your `packageVersion("sf")` ?

Comment: Hmm my current version was `0.8.0` I updated it with `0.8.1`. Now it works! Thanks for checking on your machine!